# save url when re rotate screen from landscape to protrit

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to play video on player and the video is url that I fetch from an api
so I have a channels in recycleview1 and when I click on one channel the channel start play in new activity
in that activity the player take half of screen and the rest is for recycleview2 which contain some channels for easy and fast navigate between channels

so when I open the channel from recycleview1 and it start playing then I rotate the screen to landscape it work fine then restore the screen to portrate again the channel still working

but the problem is when I click on channel from recycleview2 which lead to update the url that already played and start the new one
so each time I click on channel from recycleview2 the videoview updated to new channel url that clicked

I face problem when I rotate the screen after played channel from recycleview2 the videoview start play a channel that I clicked from recyclewview1 before clicking on new channel from recycleview2 because it return to onCreate method which build the url depend on the information passed with on click

so I used to save the instance state of url so when I rotate the screen to landscape the vidoeview still played the last channel that played

but the problem is when I re rotate the screen to portrate again the videoview here return to the first channel played when start the activity

I tried to save instance state too but it doesn't working

this is the code:

```
public class TVChannel extends AppCompatActivity implements
        TVAdapter.TVAdapterOnClickHandler {

    private VideoView videoView;
    private int position = 0;
    private String video;
    private MediaController mediaController;

    String mChannelTitle;
    String mChannelApp;
    String mChannelStreamname;
    String mChannelCat;

    TVAdapter mAdapter;
    RecyclerView mSportsList;

    private TextView mCategory;
    private TextView mErrorMessageDisplay;
    private ProgressBar mLoadingIndicator;

    Context mContext ;

    public TVItem channelObject;

    Uri vidUri;
    String myBoolean;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_tv_channel);

            ButterKnife.bind(this);

            mSportsList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_channel);
            mErrorMessageDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_error_message_display);

            mContext = this;

            channelObject = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("TVChannel");

            if (channelObject != null) {
                mChannelTitle = String.valueOf(channelObject.getTitle());
                mChannelApp = String.valueOf(channelObject.getApp());
                mChannelStreamname = String.valueOf(channelObject.getStreamName());
                mChannelCat = String.valueOf(channelObject.getCat());
            }

            mCategory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.category);
            videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

                String host = "http://ip/";
                String app = mChannelApp;
                String streamname = mChannelStreamname;
                String playlist = "playlist.m3u8";
                vidUri = Uri.parse(host).buildUpon()
                        .appendPath(app)
                        .appendPath(streamname)
                        .appendPath(playlist)
                        .build();

                videoView.setVideoURI(vidUri);

            final PlayerControlView playerControlView = (PlayerControlView) findViewById(R.id.player_control_view);

            playerControlView.setAlwaysShow(true);

            PlayerControlView.ViewHolder viewHolder = playerControlView.getViewHolder();
            viewHolder.pausePlayButton.setPauseDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.pause));
            viewHolder.pausePlayButton.setPlayDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.play));
            viewHolder.controlsBackground.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            viewHolder.currentTimeText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
//        viewHolder.totalTimeText.setTextSize(18);
            playerControlView.setNextListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(TVChannel.this, "onClick Next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            playerControlView.setPrevListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(TVChannel.this, "onClick Prev", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


            mediaController = playerControlView.getMediaControllerWrapper();

            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            videoView.seekTo(position);
            videoView.start();
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    playerControlView.show();
                }
            });


            GridLayoutManager LayoutManagerSports = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
            mSportsList.setLayoutManager(LayoutManagerSports);
            mSportsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mAdapter = new TVAdapter(this, mContext);
            mSportsList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            mLoadingIndicator = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb_loading_indicator);

            String sortchannels = mChannelCat.toLowerCase() + ".php";

            loadTVData(sortchannels);

        } else {

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_tv_channel2);

            ButterKnife.bind(this);

            mSportsList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_channel);
            mErrorMessageDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_error_message_display);

            mContext = this;

            channelObject = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("TVChannel");

            if (channelObject != null) {
                mChannelTitle = String.valueOf(channelObject.getTitle());
                mChannelApp = String.valueOf(channelObject.getApp());
                mChannelStreamname = String.valueOf(channelObject.getStreamName());
                mChannelCat = String.valueOf(channelObject.getCat());
            }

            mCategory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.category);
            videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

            if (savedInstanceState != null){

                myBoolean = savedInstanceState.getString("video");
                Toast.makeText(this, "This is my Toast message!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(myBoolean));
            }

            else {

                String host = "http://ip/";
                String app = mChannelApp;
                String streamname = mChannelStreamname;
                String playlist = "playlist.m3u8";
                vidUri = Uri.parse(host).buildUpon()
                        .appendPath(app)
                        .appendPath(streamname)
                        .appendPath(playlist)
                        .build();

                videoView.setVideoURI(vidUri);

            }

            final PlayerControlView playerControlView = (PlayerControlView) findViewById(R.id.player_control_view);

            playerControlView.setAlwaysShow(false);

            PlayerControlView.ViewHolder viewHolder = playerControlView.getViewHolder();
            viewHolder.pausePlayButton.setPauseDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.pause));
            viewHolder.pausePlayButton.setPlayDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.play));
            viewHolder.controlsBackground.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.controlBackground));
            viewHolder.currentTimeText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
//        viewHolder.totalTimeText.setTextSize(18);
            playerControlView.setNextListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(TVChannel.this, "onClick Next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            playerControlView.setPrevListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(TVChannel.this, "onClick Prev", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            mediaController = playerControlView.getMediaControllerWrapperFullScreen();

            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            videoView.seekTo(position);
            videoView.start();
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    playerControlView.show();
                }
            });


            GridLayoutManager LayoutManagerSports = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
            mSportsList.setLayoutManager(LayoutManagerSports);
            mSportsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mAdapter = new TVAdapter(this, mContext);
            mSportsList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            mLoadingIndicator = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb_loading_indicator);

            String sortchannels = mChannelCat.toLowerCase() + ".php";

            loadTVData(sortchannels);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // Store current position.
        savedInstanceState.putString("video", String.valueOf(vidUri));
        videoView.start();
    }

    // After rotating the phone. This method is called.
    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // Get saved position.
        video = savedInstanceState.getString("video");
        videoView.start();
    }


    private void loadTVData(String sortChannels) {
        showTVDataView();
        new FetchTVTask().execute(sortChannels);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(TVItem channel, View view) {

        if (channel != null) {
            mChannelTitle = String.valueOf(channel.getTitle());
            mChannelApp = String.valueOf(channel.getApp());
            mChannelStreamname = String.valueOf(channel.getStreamName());
        }

        String host = "http://ip/";
        String app = mChannelApp;
        String streamname = mChannelStreamname;
        String playlist = "playlist.m3u8";
        vidUri = Uri.parse(host).buildUpon()
                .appendPath(app)
                .appendPath(streamname)
                .appendPath(playlist)
                .build();

        videoView.setVideoURI(vidUri);

        final PlayerControlView playerControlView = (PlayerControlView) findViewById(R.id.player_control_view);
        playerControlView.setAlwaysShow(true);

        PlayerControlView.ViewHolder viewHolder = playerControlView.getViewHolder();
        viewHolder.pausePlayButton.setPauseDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.pause));
        viewHolder.pausePlayButton.setPlayDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.play));
        viewHolder.controlsBackground.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        viewHolder.currentTimeText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
//        viewHolder.totalTimeText.setTextSize(18);
        playerControlView.setNextListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(TVChannel.this, "onClick Next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        playerControlView.setPrevListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(TVChannel.this, "onClick Prev", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        videoView.setMediaController(playerControlView.getMediaControllerWrapper());
//
        videoView.seekTo(position);
        videoView.start();
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                playerControlView.show();
            }
        });

    }

    private void showTVDataView() {
        mErrorMessageDisplay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mSportsList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void showErrorMessage() {
        mSportsList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mErrorMessageDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public class FetchTVTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<TVItem>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<TVItem> doInBackground(String... params) {
            if (params.length == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            String sortChannels = params[0];
            URL channelRequestUrl = NetworkTV.buildUrl(sortChannels);

            try {
                String jsonTVResponse = NetworkTV.getResponseFromHttpUrl(channelRequestUrl);

                ArrayList<TVItem> simpleJsonTVData = JsonTV.getSimpleTVStringsFromJson(TVChannel.this, jsonTVResponse);

                return simpleJsonTVData;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<TVItem> TVData) {
            mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mCategory.setText(TVData.get(0).getCat());
            if (TVData != null) {
                showTVDataView();
                mAdapter.setTVData(TVData);
            } else {
                showErrorMessage();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

you can see that I use:

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
}

else{
}
```

to set content view for portrait and landscape

and inside else this is the code that I use to save the url in landscape mode:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null){

                myBoolean = savedInstanceState.getString("video");
                Toast.makeText(this, "This is my Toast message!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(myBoolean));
            }

            else {

                String host = "http://ip/";
                String app = mChannelApp;
                String streamname = mChannelStreamname;
                String playlist = "playlist.m3u8";
                vidUri = Uri.parse(host).buildUpon()
                        .appendPath(app)
                        .appendPath(streamname)
                        .appendPath(playlist)
                        .build();

                videoView.setVideoURI(vidUri);

            }
```

and if savedInstanceState null so build url like this from on click information that I pass in portrait mode:

```
channelObject = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("TVChannel");

                if (channelObject != null) {
                    mChannelTitle = String.valueOf(channelObject.getTitle());
                    mChannelApp = String.valueOf(channelObject.getApp());
                    mChannelStreamname = String.valueOf(channelObject.getStreamName());
                    mChannelCat = String.valueOf(channelObject.getCat());
                }
```

how can I save the url channel when I re rotate screen from landscape to portrait mode again?